# Facebook Messenger SDK in Swift, how to reply in messenger and direct user to my app.

Tags: swift, fbsdk, facebook-messenger, fbsdkmessengersharekit, fbsdksharekit

In FBMessenger when user clicks to reply using the special reply link right below the image/video that was sent from my app the user is re-directed to my app in the app store even though the app is already installed. How do I direct the user directly to my app from FBMessenger reply link?

When this is achieved I would like the user to select image/video in my app and when reply/send is selected redirect back to FBMessenger on the same thread they were on to quickly reply. Current result is sending a new message, after "send" from my app the user is redirected to messenger and have to select who to send it to like a new message.

This is what I have according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios. But when I run the app these delegate functions are not being called. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerDelegate {

    var contextFBMessenger : FBSDKMessengerContext?;
    let messengerUrlHandler = FBSDKMessengerURLHandler()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            messengerUrlHandler.delegate = self
            return true;
    }

    func messengerURLHandler(messengerURLHandler: FBSDKMessengerURLHandler!, didHandleOpenFromComposerWithContext context: FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerOpenFromComposerContext!) {
        self.contextFBMessenger = context
    }

    func messengerURLHandler(messengerURLHandler: FBSDKMessengerURLHandler!, didHandleReplyWithContext context: FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerReplyContext!) {
        self.contextFBMessenger = context
    }

}
```

Comment: Forgot to add when the user starts from the app to send a video this is how they are redirected to FB Messenger:        >  `guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else { return }
        FBSDKMessengerSharer.shareVideo(data, withOptions: nil)
        let shareOptions = FBSDKMessengerShareOptions()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
        shareOptions.contextOverride = appDelegate?.contextFBMessenger
        FBSDKMessengerSharer.shareVideo(data, withOptions: shareOptions)
`